# spring.gson.disable-html-escaping=false is not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

I am trying to use spring.gson.disable-html-escaping=false in my spring boot application.
but it is returning default value.

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
spring.gson.disable-html-escaping=false
```

GsonHttpMessageConverterConfig.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class GsonHttpMessageConverterConfig {

    @Value("${grove.gson.http.converter.mediaTypes}")
    private String configuredMediaTypes;

    @Value("${spring.gson.disable-html-escaping}")
    private String disabledHtmlEscaping;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter(Gson gson) {
        GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        List<MediaType> configuredMediaTypes =  httpConverterMediaTypes();
        if (!configuredMediaTypes.isEmpty()){
            converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(configuredMediaTypes);
        }
        converter.setGson(gson());
        System.out.println("converter.getGson().htmlSafe() : "+converter.getGson().htmlSafe());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Gson gson() {
        //String disabledHtmlEscaping = System.getenv("spring.gson.disable-html-escaping");
        final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        System.out.println("spring.gson.disable-html-escaping : "+disabledHtmlEscaping);
        return builder.create();
    }

    private List<MediaType> httpConverterMediaTypes(){
        //String configuredMediaTypes = System.getenv("grove.gson.http.converter.mediaTypes");
        if (configuredMediaTypes != null && !configuredMediaTypes.trim().equals("")){
            return Arrays.stream(configuredMediaTypes.split(","))
                    .map(mediaType -> mediaType.split("/"))
                    .map(mediaType -> new MediaType(mediaType[0],mediaType[1]))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

can somebody help me why that property is not working.
I dont want to use **builder.disableHtmlEscaping().create()**
output is :

```
2022-03-28 11:20:06.930  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2022-03-28 11:20:06.980  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-28 11:20:06.980  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1290 ms
spring.gson.disable-html-escaping : false
converter.getGson().htmlSafe() : true
2022-03-28 11:20:07.730  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-03-28 11:20:07.735  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-03-28 11:20:07.774  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-28 11:20:07.789  INFO 11920 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.566 seconds (JVM running for 2.965)
```

the expected output is :
converter.getGson().htmlSafe() is should return false if

Comment: Isn't this the correct behavior? "disable ... = false" is a double negative. "html-escaping" and "html safe" refer to the same setting, so `htmlSafe()` returning `true` seems correct. It looks there is also explicitly a [unit test for this property](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/6865f1f3d913a40192570d51857664edd2ed5a48/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/gson/GsonAutoConfigurationTests.java#L191-L194). (Though maybe I am missing something)

Comment: hello @Marcono1234, thank you for reply... builder.disableHtmlEscaping().create() this will return converter.getGson().htmlSafe()  as false and anything i am setting in properties for spring.gson.disable-html-escaping is not reflecting.

Comment: I just found out that the parser for this acts like: is the config key present? if yes, then TRUE, and it doesn't care if the value is false. Remove the value from the config completely if you want the html escaping behave as the default (enabled). To your next comment - if you override it with disableHtmlEscaping(), anything you do with html escaping in the config is thrown out of the window. You override it by that.